# Convert ASCII file to binary file - efficient methods

Tags: delphi, binary, ascii, delphi-7, binaryfiles

I am trying to convert an ASCII file to a binary file. This is for an integration where they are expecting a binary file from me.

I tried a few of the things to achieve the same.

**Method1**

```
function TForm1.ReadString(var fd: File): string;
var
  count: Cardinal;
  l: integer;
begin
  BlockRead(fd, l, SizeOf(integer), count);
  SetLength(Result, l);
  BlockRead(fd, Result[1], l, count);
end;

procedure TForm1.WriteString(var fd: File; str: string);
var
  count: Cardinal;
  l: integer;
begin
  l := Length(str);
  BlockWrite(fd, l, SizeOf(integer), count);
  BlockWrite(fd,str[1], l, count);
end;
```

Using above methods I am unable to get back the original string to verify if this works fine.

So tried another method:

**Method2**

```
procedure TForm1.convertobinary2;
var
  lFS: TFileStream;
  lBuf: TBytes;
  lFullFileName: string;
  SourceFile: Tstringlist;
  StreamData: TStream;
begin

  lFullFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Binary.txt';
  SourceFile := Tstringlist.Create;
  SourceFile.LoadFromFile('D:\Text File');

  StreamData := TStream.Create;

  StringToStream(StreamData, SourceFile.Text);

  lFS := TFileStream.Create(lFullFileName, fmCreate);
  try
    SetLength(lBuf, StreamData.Size);
    StreamData.Position := 0;
    StreamData.ReadBuffer(lBuf[0], StreamData.Size);

    lFS.WriteBuffer(lBuf[0], StreamData.Size);
  finally
    lFS.Free;
    FreeandNil(SourceFile);
    FreeandNil(StreamData);
  end;
end;
```

Here I get an exception raised when trying to ReadBuffer.

```
 Exception class EStreamError with message 'TStream.Seek not implemented'
```

Would really appreciate if someone can point me to right direction.

a) Which is the efficient way to convert ASCII file to a binary file? 
b) What exactly happens when we try to convert ASCII string to binary?

Comment: What do you mean by ASCII file to binary? Any file is binary. Please explain exactly what you’re trying to achieve

Comment: "Exception class EStreamError with message 'TStream.Seek not implemented'" is because you're creating an instance of TStream. Both of your methods look like they're attempting to copy the file exactly as-is (i.e no conversion of any kind)

Comment: Method 1 won't work in D2009+ since `string` is `UnicodeString` and `SizeOf(Char)=2`. Have `WriteString()` convert to UTF-8 before writing to file. Have `ReadString()` convert from UTF-8 after reading from file.

Comment: Method 2 can be simplified by eliminating `lBuf`. Use `TStream.CopyFrom()` to copy `StreamData` to `lFS`. Or get rid of `lFS` by using a `TStringStream` with a `TEncoding`, or `TFile.WriteAllText()`, to write a string directly to file.

Answer (score 1):

```
function TForm1.ReadString(var fd: File): string;
var
  count: Cardinal;
  l: integer;
  {$ifdef UNICODE }
    u8: Utf8String;
  {$endif }
begin
  BlockRead(fd,l,SizeOf(integer),count);
  {$ifdef UNICODE }
    SetLength(u8,l);
    if l>0 then BlockRead(fd,u8[1],l,count);
    Result:=u8;
  {$else }
    SetLength(Result,l);
    if l>0 then BlockRead(fd,Result[1],l,count);
  {$endif }
end;

procedure TForm1.WriteString(var fd: File; const str: string);
var
  count: Cardinal;
  l: integer;
  {$ifdef UNICODE }
    u8: UTF8String;
  {$endif }
begin
  {$ifdef UNICODE }
    u8 := str;
    l := Length(u8);
    BlockWrite(fd,l,SizeOf(integer),count);
    if l>0 then BlockWrite(fd,u8[1],l,count);
  {$else }
    l := Length(str);
    BlockWrite(fd,l,SizeOf(integer),count);
    if l>0 then BlockWrite(fd,str[1],l,count);
  {$endif }
end;
```

The above functions will work in both Unicode and ANSI versions of the compiler. Please note, however, that data isn't compatible between different versions (Unicode /ANSI) of the compile. A file created by a Unicode version of the compiler cannot be read (without some modifications) by an ANSI version of the compiler, or vice-versa.

Also note, that the data saved to the file is ANSI in ANSI versions of the compiler and UTF-8 (8-bit Unicode ) in Unicode versions of the compiler.

The interface to the program is in both instances the native STRING type of the compiler (AnsiString in ANSI compilers, UnicodeString in Unicode compilers).

Also note that untyped files are not efficient (speedwise) to use. You should use Stream-based file functions like in your Method2. Use TFileStream or - even better if multiple small pieces of data are read from/written to the file - TBufferedFileStream and not TStream, which is a stream without any backing data, i.e. no file or memory is associated with it, and thus it cannot be used directly.

Comment: @Hearware I will try and let you know, Thank you

Comment: @mano Do you make progress in letting him know?